# How do i install focal fossa software on groovy gorilla from ppa

Tags: package-management, ppa, repository, 20.10

I have Ubuntu 20.10. I am trying to install Handbrake from its ppa. when  i added handbrake repositories and ran `sudo apt update` i got the following message

> Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu groovy InRelease
> Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu groovy Release
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
> Reading package lists... Done
> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I went to the repository and tried to  manually search for groovy packages and found none but there was a focal fossa package.What should i do?

BTW

- snap packages are outdated
- I am facing the same issue for other software also.(eg - f.lux...many more)

### Edit

As per Guiverc's advice i decided to use a flatpak instead. **but i would still like to know how to install a package made for older version of Ubuntu from ppa as i encounter this problem often with programs which are no longer maintained**.

Comment: You risk creating problems for yourself come *release-upgrade* time (ie. what you want to do is easy, but you'll likely find moving to *hirsute* much more difficult, ie. solving a problem now but creating a bigger problem in the near future..). That's one  reason (*dependencies*) that personal package archives are built for specific releases...  That isn't a very good solution, if you don't know what you're doing, you could just be creating problems that will bite you rather soon (ie. when you move on from *groovy*, unless you plan on re-install to upgrade).

Comment: @guiverc so should i just wait?.....

Comment: The choice is yours, a single word needs to be changed in the source (*a word copied from your question title replaces a keyword in the entry also seen in your error paste*) so what you want is really easy (change a single word), but my point was this will likely bite you when you try and move to *hirsute* (ie. *release-upgrade* time) unless you've done your homework for all packages & dependencies; the fact that you're asking *how* makes me feel you're not ready for that yet (unless you're happy with at least potentially needing to re-install to upgrade..)

Comment: FYI: using an older/earlier source (focal) in a later release (groovy) is less risky than the reverse.. but the potential for problems is still there.  I would look for alternate solution(s) that contain less risk, esp. on non-LTS releases where you'll need to *release-upgrade* somewhat often...

Answer (score 4):

The package `handbrake` is in Ubuntu's `universe` repository for Groovy.

All you need to do to install it:

If you added a PPA to your sources, remove it.  Make sure that you have `universe` enabled.  Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install handbrake
```

No need for a PPA. No need to risk destroying your package management system or your sources list. No need for a snap.

Comment: its outdated.Latest version is 1.3.3 not 1.3.1

Comment: How is that relevant to what you need to do with the software?  Ubuntu rarely ships bleeding edge software. Latest versions of software lack testing and support. Do you really need that version for some reason?  See: https://askubuntu.com/q/151283

Comment: I updated my question.thanks for the answer+1.

Comment: it does not answer my question.my question was "How do i install focal fossa software on groovy gorilla from ppa" i just edited my question to make that point clearer :)